# How to extract a size of an object from a image

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, data-science, opencv3.0

I'm attempting to assemble a pipeline that can predict the size of a object given an image i.e predict the size in unit X given a photo of a apple.

From what I have looked at there are not any training sets that have a calibration object that have been training alongside; my actual problem is to extract the nutritional information (roughly speaking) from a food group - once I know the foods w*h or bounding box area I can then have everything I need to accurately count calories.

As mentioned above lightly there is only one way of doing this that I am aware of and that's training a classifier with a calibration object; so images could be taken here and grouped into a class for the object that you're calibrating such as a Dime or Penny, credit card etc. something with static dimensions.

What is throwing me off a little bit is if there is a better way of doing things and if there are please share additionally, if there are any pre-trained models that have been calibrated using a static object that could be used to estimate the size of a object given any image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the definition of your problem, I don't think you should train your classifier to predict the size of the object. You might want to train NN to identify some common object (dime, penny, CC etc) and train another network to identify foods. Once you put your "calibration" object near the plate, you can easily normalize the image and calculate food's size.